# No sound on HDMI Ubuntu 20.04 (Another case of...)

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have an HTPC (AMD Ryzen 3 2200G on GIGABYTE B450M S2H) connected through HDMI to my Denon AVR-X1400H receiver. This is an always on system and I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-59-generic x86_64).

I use the receiver for other inputs as well, and it goes to sleep after inactivity. When I turn the receiver back on, the sound doesn't work on the Ubuntu system.

Observation: I have also lost the sound on occasions where the receiver wasn't turned off/didn't go to sleep. Likely, when the Ubuntu system went to sleep (or at least the screen went dark after some period of inactivity).

So I checked the *Sound* settings, which show two output devices:

- *Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Family 17th (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller* - this was preselected, and not the one I want.
- *HDMI / DisplayPort - Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller* (see screenshot).

  [image: screenshot]

I know this is the correct one. It also appears in the dropdown menu. I'm able to select it but that doesn't help. After clicking on *Test*, I don't see any of the 5.1 connected speakers this time. Other times, as I'll explain later, I do see them, but after clicking on them, I don't hear the test sound. Also, this used to work in the past (see note at the end).

In PulseAudio Volume Control, the HDMI/DisplayPort device isn't shown at all, only the *Digital Output (S/PDIF)* one. I do see both in the configuration tab, though:

[image: -screenshot]

For testing the sound output, I tried to play something on YouTube or Netflix. Interestingly, when the sound problem manifests itself, I expect for the video to play silently, but even the video doesn't play at all. I'm able to seek to different positions in the video streams (and I get a still image for that particular position) and YouTube shows a spinning wheel and this message:

> If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device.

Not sure if/how this relates, but perhaps it may be helpful for diagnosing the problem, since this doesn't happen once the sound gets working again.

I restarted the system and the *Sound* options changed: The correct Output Device (*HDMI/DisplayPort - Raven...*) is now selected, and now there are *Configuration*, *Fade*, and *Subwoofer* fields beneath, which weren't there before the restart:

[image: screenshot]

Perhaps this is a good sign, but there's still no sound. There are three options in the dropdown menu: *5.1*, *7.1*, *Stereo*. The correct option, *5.1*, is preselected, and I also tried changing to the others, but this had no effect.

This time, after clicking the *Test* button, all 5.1 speakers are visible:

[image: screenshot]

However, if I click on them, no sound comes out.

There are changes in PulseAudio Volume Control too. HDMI is now among the output devices. The green checkmark button (Set as fallback) is selected. Clicking the padlock (Lock channels together) reveals all 5.1 volume selectors:

[image: screenshot]

As I wrote above, despite these positive looking changes after the restart, there is still no sound. Interestingly, in the *Playback* tab of the PulseAudio Volume Control application, there's only the *Front Left* and *Front Right* channels for the 5.1 HDMI output, despite all 5.1 being shown in the *Output Devices* tab (not sure if this is expected, or relevant, just trying to document everything the best I can).

This is what my `alsamixer` looks like:

[image: screenshots - F6 - sound card selection]

[image: sound card 0]

[image: sound card 1]

I tried to change the *Profile* option under the *Configuration* tab. The correct profile, *Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output*, was selected, but I wanted to see if changing it would do anything. As a result, the HDMI output disappeared from the list in the *Output Devices* tab and the *Brave: Playback* entry in the *Playback* tab changed accordingly, since there was now only one output device, *Digital Output (S/PDIF)*.

So I tried another restart. Still no sound. Another restart, and another, and all of a sudden, "magically", the sound is back. I have no idea what brought it back or what the problem that disabled it in the first place was. I checked the *Sound* settings, PulseAudio Volume Control, and `alsamixer` to see if I could spot anything that changed, but no. All settings and options appear just as they were before. I also checked the speaker *Test* button, but despite the sound working now overall, clicking on the individual speakers does not. There's no sound output. So the thing that makes this annoying problem all the more confusing is that it appears like I have three states:

1. HDMI output is missing and there's no sound.
2. HDMI output is back, all the settings (GUI, at least, in *Sound* settings, PulseAudio Volume Control, and `alsamixer`) appear alright, but there's still no sound.
3. The *Sound* settings, PulseAudio Volume Control, and `alsamixer` appear just as before, but the sound works.

The sound disappeared again while I was composing this write-up, and now, even after a dozen restarts, I was not able to get the sound working again.

I did also go though the other threads on this forum (and a few others) and I tried:

```
sudo killall pulseaudio; rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -rf ~/.pulse*
```

This resulted in removing the devices, and I was left with a *Dummy Output*. After a restart, I was back to the beginning: *Digital Output (S/PDIF)* preselected. When I change it to the correct *HDMI/ DisplayPort - Raven/Raven2/Fe...* and select the correct profile *Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output* as before, I actually saw the *Output Device* disappear in front of me in PulseAudio Volume Control window which I had previously opened right next to the *Sound* settings window. Another restart and I'm at stage 2: devices and settings appear fine but still no sound.

I also tried:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

and it was the same thing, I got a *Dummy Output* device and *No cards available for configuration* in the *Configuration* tab of PulseAudio Volume Control.

Interestingly, I first ran it with `sudo`:

```
sudo pulseaudio -k
```

and got this error:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
```

Here's some additional info to help with diagnostics:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01)
01:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
02:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
02:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
02:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c8)
09:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
09:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
09:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
09:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1
09:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
0a:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
```

I admit I have very little idea what I'm doing and I'm hoping someone more Ubuntu savvy can suggest things to try to diagnose and fix the issue. I will happily add any logs that you might need and report the outcome of your suggestions. Many thanks!

*Note, just for context: I have been having similar sound problems with this system in the past. These were similar but not the same: back then, my 5 speakers used to play fine (also in the Speaker Test), but occasionally my subwoofer output disappeared (the subwoofer volume slider was at 0 and greyed out). A log out or restart would usually solve this. Now I'm experiencing no sound at all, and a single log out/restart doesn't help.*